# how does fileServingEnabled="false" in ibm-web-ext.xmi loads static file

Tags: java, webserver, websphere-6.1, appserver, ibmhttpserver

We are using app server: IBM WAS 6.1 and web server: IBM HTTP Server.

Issue is explained below

1. I know that **fileServingEnabled="true"** in **ibm-web-ext.xmi** helps in loading static content. And when fileServingEnabled="false", none of the static content gets loaded.
2. Now the problem is that  this is behaving excatly same way in our development enviorment but in test and production enviormnet I see that we are using : **fileServingEnabled="false"** in ibm-web-ext.xmi. And all the **static content gets downloaded successfully**.
3. **So my question is that do we need any other setting as well to download static content,  which could explain that why its working fine even after making fileServingEnabled="false".**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only case that comes to my mind in which it would work is, if you have HTTP Server on the same box, and either static resources are put in the HTTP server directory folders or if you have configured alias in httpd.conf pointing to the installed web application. In general with `fileServingEnabled="false"` WebSphere will not serve static content.

Comment: @Gas I dont have much information about these web servers and app servers setting. It would be great if you can guide some good resource for what u explained before

Comment: See some general info in [Handling Static Content in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0211_brown/brown.html), although it is about old version, most of the information is still relevant.

Comment: @Gas Thanks, this link is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Good Link...    The key from the web server perspective (IHS) is the plugin-cfg.xml file.  If you want the application server to to serve static pages then defining a uri for the application to be contextroot/* would pass all uri's matching that pattern to the application server.  Defining a uri of /* would pass everthing to the application server.   For IHS to handle the request the Plug-in must not match the uri request.  Additional information relating to the IBM HTTP Server on this topic can be found at

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/plugin_alter_uri.html

See also

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/plugin_questions.html